# Groovy Json - get array element size and parse with element count

Tags: json, groovy

My Json file

```
{
    "Apps": [
    {
      "ClientName": "abc",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "ClientName": "b",
      "Version": "1.0"
    }
  ]

}
```

In the above JSON file created with a single array along with multiple elements (name, value pair)

I want to calculate how many elements are there in the array [Apps] using groovy.
Based on the count I'm going to create a loop and parse elements one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to process elements one by one you don't need a count. It can be accomplished using standard iteration methods:

```
def txt = '{     "Apps": [     {       "ClientName": "abc",       "Version": "1.0"     },     {       "ClientName": "b",       "Version": "1.0"     }   ]  }'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText txt

println "count = ${json.Apps.size()}"

json.Apps.each this.&println
```

prints:

```
count = 2
[ClientName:abc, Version:1.0]
[ClientName:b, Version:1.0]
```